# Issue consuming asmx webservice from classic asp

Tags: javascript, .net, web-services, asmx

I am getting the below error when i tried to consume the asmx web service(from asp.net website) from classic asp. 
         Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

```
    [![IIS Server Error][1]][1]
```

Below is my ServiceRequest.asp page code which resides under my classic asp website

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function callService() {
            url = GetUrl("/WebService1.asmx/CallService")
            var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr1.open("POST", url);
            xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            xhr1.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr1.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr1.status === 200) {
                    //var outputData = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(xhr1.responseText).d);
                    var outputData = JSON.parse(xhr1.responseText).d;

                    alert(outputData);
                    //Here the response object needs to be read
                } else if (xhr1.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr1.status != 200) {

                    //In case of SAP call failure, alert the user
                    alert("Vendor creation failed");
                }
            };

            xhr1.send(JSON.stringify({
                sVndNum: "",
                sVndName: "",
                sCoCode: "",
                sVndCity: "",
                sVndPstlCd: "",
                sVndState: "",
                sVndCntry: ""
            }));
        }

        function GetUrl(url) {
            return window.location.origin + url;
        }
    </script>


Both the classic asp application and Asp.net website which has my webservice are hosted in IIS. When I tried to access service method from classic page i am getting the below error response at service side.
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
   [ParseError][2]    


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIKR4.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YQtj.png
```

Comment: Show us some code and we might be able to tell you what's wrong with it.  Where is Classic ASP involved? That is an asp.net error page, which suggests that you're using an asp.net page rather than a classic asp page to read your web service.

Comment: I am getting below parse error:Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'VendorGenerationService'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/VendorGenerationService.vb" Class="VendorGenerationService" %>

Comment: @John - I have included both the classic page code and asmx webservice code . I tried to call webmethod from classic asp's javascript code.Then I am getting the above parse error.

Comment: Is this the same issue in your previous post [Internal Server Error(500) when try consume ASMX webservice from plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696889/internal-server-error500-when-try-consume-asmx-webservice-from-plain-javascrip)? The error is in your web service part. This has nothing to do with [asp-classic]

Comment: Yes. I am getting the below error at service side. Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'VendorGenerationService'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/VendorGenerationService.vb" Class="VendorGenerationService" %>. Please help me in fix the issue

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.  It might be on a page which uses Classic ASP somewhere else but the code you've provided is client side JavaScript, you might want to re-tag it as such.  One thought though - have you tried using the full url - ie: `url = GetUrl("https://yourdomain.com/path-to/WebService1.asmx/CallService")`

Comment: Yes. I am using full url only

Comment: @John - I am getting the exception: System.InvalidOperationException: No web service found at. I checked everything.Path everything is correct.I am struggling to fix the issue for more than a week. I followed many solutions from stack overflow for this same error .But unfortunately nothing helped me out. Please help me out.